# AWS S3 SDKv2 and image upload ios on turk

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk, awss3transfermanager

I uploaded  image to AWS S3 with with code :

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathComp];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage,0.9) writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
    filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:///private%@", filePath];
    NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
    uploadRequest.key = key;
    uploadRequest.body = fileUrl;
    uploadRequest.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
```

It's uploaded normally, but in mechanical turk i can't open preview

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finded solution for AWS SDK v2  by PaulTaykalo

```
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/10
```

Link for fixed method 
http://pastie.org/9340740

> Also added this code to swizzled method

`[headers setValue:contentType forKey:@"Content-Type"];`

Answer (score 0):

When creating a file URL using `NSURL`, you should use `+ fileURLWithPath:`. You should change this line

```
NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
```

to

```
NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

You should double check if the file was successfully uploaded using the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/).

Also, by default, all Amazon S3 resources - buckets, objects, and related subresources - are private: only the resource owner, an AWS account that created it, can access the resource. You can modify [`ACL`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3PutObjectRequest.html#//api/name/ACL) to change the permission.

Comment: Not working for me. Image can be downloaded by rightclick and Save as from MechTurk. It's only error  on opening preview at site page